# how can i export this select result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have select statement which return data as a new virtual column called new_iata_code

i want to make it as real column with this data and export it with the table.**how to do this?**

```
    select cni.*,
// this statment return data as new column called  (new_iata_code )
           (select iata_code
            from cities_iata ci
            order by pow(cni.latitude - ci.latitude, 2) + pow(cni.longitude - ci.longitude, 2)
            limit 1
           ) as new_iata_code
// the table name is cities_no_iata cni
    from cities_no_iata cni;
```

**// the update code dont work**

```
update cities_no_iata join
       (select cni.*,
               (select iata_code
                from cities_iata ci
                order by pow(cia.latitude - ci.latitude, 2) + pow(cia.longitude - ci.longitude, 2)
                limit 1
               ) as new_iata_code
        from cities_no_iata cni
       ) upd
       on cities_no_iata.latitude = upd.latitude and
          cities_no_iata.longitude = upd.longitude
     set iata_code = upd.iata_code;
```

Comment: You want to add field to table and do update on whole table?

Comment: i do it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create TEMPORARY table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp select cni.*,
           (select iata_code
            from cities_iata ci
            order by pow(cni.latitude - ci.latitude, 2) + pow(cni.longitude - ci.longitude, 2)
            limit 1
           ) as new_iata_code
    from cities_no_iata cni
```

And then immediately UPDATE:

```
UPDATE cities_no_iata c
INNER JOIN tmp t on c.id = t.id //or what ever id column is named
SET c.new_iata_code = t.new_iata_code
```